# ADO.NET VB.NET ExecuteScaler method

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I'm working on some old code and there are lots of ambiguities that I am trying to explain away. There is alot of this...

```
If cmd.ExecuteScalar() <> 0 Then myUID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

So the above code doesn't sit well with me. It seems to me that the ExecuteScaler method is being executed twice. Therefor 2X db query executions. Could anyone advise me on whether this approach is inherrently bad.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do...

```
myUID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

`ExecuteScalar()` will return an `object`, so you will need to parse this to an `Int` and then check the value of `myUID` and decide how to handle if from there.  This way, you're hitting the DB once.

```
myUID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) //assuming myUID is Int32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim tmp As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    If Not tmp Is Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(tmp) AndAlso CInt(tmp) <> 0 Then
        myUID = CInt(tmp)
    End If
```